# What is the meaning of "Word Problem" in free algebras

Tags: reference-request, terminology, lie-algebras

I am looking for a clear definition of Word Problem in free Lie algebras. May you please describe that?

Comment: Consider the ground ring $R$ as an oracle and a set $I$. The word problem inputs an element in the free (non-associative non-unital non-Lie) $R$-algebra over the indeterminates $(x_i)_{i\in I}$, and outputs yes/no according to whether it represents $0$ in the free Lie algebra. Actually, the word problem then is solvable, the issue is rather to have a good algorithm. Keyword: Lyndon basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word problem is, in general, the problem of deciding whether two words in the generators of a given Lie algebra actually represent the same element.

There does exist [a wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_problem_for_groups) about the word problem for groups, which seems to give a pretty good description. The problem is the same for Lie algebras; these are algebraic objects which can also be concisely described using generators and relations.

There appears to have been some work done on this problem, for example [here](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4613-9730-4_2), although I do not have access to this document.

For an example (I'll stick to group theory since the idea is the same), look at for example the [dihedral group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_group). A presentation of $D_n$ is

$$\langle r,s | r^n = s^2 = (rs)^2 = 1 \rangle.$$

Suppose that $n=4$. Then we have the dihedral group of order $8$ on our hands. But what if I wrote down two words in the generators... say, $r^3$ and $srs$. These look different.

However, I know that $r^3 r = r^4 = 1 \implies r^3 = r^{-1}$

and $rsrs = (rs)^2 = 1 \implies srs = r^{-1}.$

The two words which I wrote down actually represent the same element. See? Tricky right?

Comment: Thank you for nice example

Comment: I would appreciate it if you could also provide an explanation on the concept of "Undecidability"?